# Laravel - cart mvc - where should i put functions?

Tags: laravel, cart

I am creating a cart on my website, everything is stored in session as serialized array.

I want to have helping functions like 'getPrize', 'getCart' and so on. Where should i store these functions?

example : 'getPrize' function will get the serialized array from session, foreach products and return final prize.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a simple shopping cart implementation like https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart IMO. It already answers to all of your questions. If you don't want to use it, you can have a look at the source code, I think you will find some answers in it.

Now, about your question without using a lib, you can just build a Cart class extending `Model` (with all your method like `getPrize` and `getCart`), injecting `Session` in it, make a Service Provider for this class and then inject it in your controller.

Hope it will help.